# MLFlow eval_and_log_metrics issue with binary classification

Tags: mlflow

I was trying to assess metrics for the binary classification and got a very weird result. It appears that eval_and_log_metrics won't be able to tell which one is the true positive in the "y_test". So it just averages out true positive and true negative, which gave an inflated recall metrics. How to pass the true positive value (let's say "churned") to the eval_and_log_metrics?

metrics = mlflow.sklearn.eval_and_log_metrics(model, X_test, y_test, prefix="test_")

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I call eval_and_log_metrics(), how does it know I am trying to predict target='churned', rather than target='retained'? It's binary with custom target value. Ideally we can add an argument to specify which target value to predict and get corresponding metrics. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `mlflow.sklearn.eval_and_log_metrics` is computing multi-class classification metrics with `average="weighted"` parameter [code](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/41deb9ee5705d2727dc3df7fe60ce2c09231c8cc/mlflow/sklearn/utils.py#L192-L213). I just created a feature request to support binary classification metrics with a `pos_label`: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/5512.